# How can I set localization in flutter custom library?

Tags: flutter

I've created some lib in my project. There are a lot of words and phrases, so I must translate everything.
I set the app's language using bloc but I don't know how to use it in my custom library.
I think I should use something related to context. I don't know at all.
Help me, please.

It's my class for localizations.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

import 'constants/constants.dart';

class AppLocalizations {
  Locale locale;

  AppLocalizations(this.locale);

  /// Helper method to keep the code in the widgets concise
  /// Localizations are accessed using an InheritedWidget "of" syntax
  static AppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
    return Localizations.of(context, AppLocalizations);
  }

  /// Static member to have a simple access to the delegate from the MaterialApp
  static const LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> delegate =
      _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  late Map<String, String> _localizedStrings;

  Future<bool> load() async {
    String jsonString =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/langs/${locale.languageCode}.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);

    _localizedStrings = jsonMap.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key, value.toString());
    });

    return true;
  }

  String? translate(String key) {
    return _localizedStrings[key];
  }
}

class _AppLocalizationsDelegate
    extends LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> {
  const _AppLocalizationsDelegate();

  // add all languages code here
  @override
  bool isSupported(Locale locale) {
    return LanguageKeys.LANGUAGE_KEYS_LIST.contains(locale.languageCode);
  }

  // load all localization files
  @override
  Future<AppLocalizations> load(Locale locale) async {
    AppLocalizations localizations = new AppLocalizations(locale);
    await localizations.load();
    return localizations;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReload(LocalizationsDelegate<AppLocalizations> old) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about bloc pattern since I have always used provider.

But the basic step would be:

(1) Inject the AppLocalizations class localization into material app

```
MaterialApp(
  supportedLocales: [
    Locale('en'),
    Locale('es'),
  ],
  localizationsDelegates: [
    AppLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
    for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
      if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale.languageCode &&
          supportedLocale.countryCode == locale.countryCode) {
        return supportedLocale;
      }
    }
    return supportedLocales.first;
  },
  locale: Locale('en'), // translate to this language
  .......
);
```

(2) For any translation pass the key to Applocalization

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("understood")
```

You can change translate method in **AppLocalizations** class

(3) If you want to change app locale/lang add your stateful variable to locale key in Material App and put the Consumer above **MaterialApp** itself.

```
ChangeNotifierProvider<LangSettingsProvider>(
      create: (_) => LangSettingsProvider(),
      child: Consumer<LangSettingsProvider>(
        builder: (context, lang, _) {
          return MaterialApp(
           locale : lang.appLocal
          
       ....
```

(4) Include assets inside assets folder and specify in the pubspec yml file

```
  assets:
    - assets/icon/
    - assets/lang/en.json
    - assets/lang/es.json
```

(5) Sample of the json key value pair

```
//en.json 
"understood":"Understood",
//es.json
"understood":"Entendido",
```

Comment: Okey. I did it in the beginning. What about the library which I include in my project? this localization file isn't in the library and I can't get it there

Comment: @alexsafsafsd the AppLocalizations class is the same one in your question. I just explained you how to attach that class with the Material App

Comment: @AtishShakya How we can achieve this via the `flutter_localizations` plugin? whatever text I want to localize in the custom library, I have to define the same key-value pair in the app as well.